# Stanford Core NLP parsing with CSV

Tags: java, csv, nlp

Basically I am using Stanford core NLP to extract data from a local CSV and have hit a problem it parses through 117 records but seems to then break and I have changed a few things and can't figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] sentences = newLine.split(splitcsv);
```

This splits on `,`, but in your example string there is no comma and `sentences` will only have one element.

Then you try to access `sentences[3]` without a check first:

```
store.add(sentences[3]);
```

Which will be invalid, and causes `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.